# Passing data from SOAP request to SOAP response in Script Dispatch of Mock Service

Tags: xml, soap, groovy, soapui

I am using `Script` Dispatch of *Mock Service* in SoapUI

Sample request content

```
<upload>
   <uploadtext>This is my first upload text</uploadtext>
   <uploadtext>second upload text</uploadtext>
</upload>
```

My requirement is to pass same information to my response

```
<upload>
       <uploadtext>${uploadText1}</uploadtext>
       <uploadtext>${uploadText2}</uploadtext>
</upload>
```

I am using `SoapUI` and trying to achieve using groovy script. I am novice in groovy, please let me know if there is any other easy way it can done.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
import javax.xml.xpath.*
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.lang.Binding
import groovy.lang.Script

def util = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContext)
def uploadText1 = xml.body.upload.uploadtext[0]
def uploadText2 = xml.body.upload.uploadtext[1]
//above uploadText1 and uploadText2 are storing values from my request
//however I am struggling to assign these values to response 
context.setProperty("UploadText", uploadText1)
context.setProperty("UploadText", uploadText2)
```

Not able to see my response same as request

Appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is becuase you are not adding the required properties to the context.

Chang below statements.
**From:**

```
context.setProperty("UploadText", uploadText1)
context.setProperty("UploadText", uploadText2)
```

**To:**

```
context.uploadText1 = uploadText1
context.uploadText2 = uploadText2
```

By the way, other suggestions (if there is nothing else to do in the `Script` Dispatch:

- Not required any `import` statements
- Not required the statement `def util`

Comment: Glad you find it helpful and able to understand it.